# C++ Move Constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

What is the correct way of using or creating a move constructor?

Here is an example:

```
class Example
{
public:
    Example( int && p_Number,
             bool && p_YesNo,
             std::string && p_String ) : // Error here
             Number( p_Number ),
             YesNo( p_YesNo ),
             String( p_String )
    {
    };

private:
    int Number;
    bool YesNo;
    std::string String;
    std::vector< unsigned char > Vector;
};

void ShowExample( void )
{
    Example ExampleA( 2013,
                      true,
                      "HelloWorld" // Why won't it work?
                      );
};
```

I've shown the errors in the comment.

**Edit:**
**Okay, I am now sure what I have is not a move constructor. So, can I write one?**

Comment: You should show the specific error, not your comment on the error. `"HelloWorld"` is `const`. Are you accounting for this?

Comment: `"HelloWorld" // Why won't it work?` If you're using VC++ 2010, it's because of a bug (fixed in VC++ 2012).

Comment: You'd say `String(std::move(p_String))` etc. But what you have is not *the* "move constructor". I'd rather call "a moving constructor".

Comment: It's not a move constructor nor a moving constructor. Nothing will be moved. It'll just only accept rvalues. :(

Comment: @KerrekSB Its not? How would I take my "moving constructor" (lol) and make an actual "move constructor"?

Comment: @KerrekSB How can I make a move constructor then?

Comment: @tadman it's a const char* which implicitly constructs a temporary std::string, eligible for move semantics. However with some GCC versions (I can't recall which ones since I use several in parallel) one has to explicitly write `String(std::move(p_String))` in the initializer list.

Comment: @user2117427 there can be only one move constructor per class: `className(className&&)` just like there is only one copy constructor per class: `className(const className&)` but you still can have constructors that accept rvalues (ie. move semantics) on specific arguments. It's just a name issue.

Comment: @syam, you _always_ need to say `String(std::move(p_String))` to move it, because `p_String` is not an rvalue

Comment: @JonathanWakely then there is a bug in some GCC versions which don't require the explicit `std::move` and *yet* call a move constructor for the member. Now, I didn't dig too far in the C++11 standard so I'll take your word for it that `std::move` is *always* required in this case, especially since I seem to recall that the GCC versions that don't need it are older ones. ;) Thanks for the precision.

Comment: At one point the C++0x draft allowed lvalues to bind to an rvalue reference, but even for versions of GCC implementing that spec `String(p_String)` would prefer a copy constructor to a move constructor if both exist

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, there is no reason to write a move constructor for that class.  The compiler generated one will do just fine.  But if you were to write it, it might look something like this:

```
Example(Example && rhs)
    :Number(rhs.Number)
    ,YesNo(rhs.YesNo)
    ,String(std::move(rhs.String))
    ,Vector(std::move(rhs.Vector))
{}
```

You can, if you want, for consistency, call `std::move` on the `int` and the `bool`, but you won't gain anything from it.

For that other constructor, with all the arguments, the simplest thing to do is this:

```
Example(int p_Number, bool p_YesNo, std::string p_String)
    :Number(p_Number)
    ,YesNo(p_YesNo)
    ,String(std::move(p_String))
{}
```

In response to your comment below:

A move constructor is invoked whenever you try to construct an object with an R-value of the same type as the only constructor argument.  For example, when an object is returned by value from a function, that is an R-value, although often in that case, copying and moving is skipped altogether.  A case where you can create an R-value is by calling `std::move` on an L-value.  For example:

```
Example ex1(7, true, "Cheese"); // ex1 is an L-value
Example ex2(std::move(ex1));    // moves constructs ex2 with ex1
```

Comment: Thanks! I can understand that there is really no point of using a move constructor for the example class. But its an example. I have a question. How would I declare an object that will be using the move constructor?

Answer (score 5):

A move constructor takes an *rvalue* reference to another object of the same type, and moves the other object's resources to the new object, for example:

```
Example(Example && other) :
    Number(other.Number),             // no point in moving primitive types
    YesNo(other.YesNo),
    String(std::move(other.String)),  // move allocated memory etc. from complex types
    Vector(std::move(other.Vector))
{}
```

Although, unless your class is itself managing resources, there's no point in writing this at all - the implicit move constructor will do exactly the same thing as the one I wrote.